# Replace stylesheet name with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex

I need to change stylesheet with javascript, but I have to replace only the name. I have tried with a lot of regex but I can't do it works (I am very bad with regex..)

This is my code right now:

```
url = jQuery('#skins-css').attr('href' );
newHref= url.replace(/\\/g,'/').replace( /.*\//, '' ).replace( /\..*/, '' );
newHref2= url.replace(newHref, color_style);
jQuery('#skins-css').attr('href', 'newHref2');
```

I need to replace the stylesheet name with color_style variable.

EDIT:

This is the original link:

http://localhost/projects/themescreators/seven-host/wp-content/themes/7host/style.css?ver=4.0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />

Comment: I think you need to provide more information: What's the input? What's the expected output? Where does your solution fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set up the second parameter in your last line of code as a string instead of a variable.  Try this:

```
jQuery('#skins-css').attr('href', newHref2);
```

Also, you should provide more context about what you want to do with your Regex.  As the question currently stands we can't help without more information.

**EDIT:** I just saw the link you posted and it appears to be a local project (you're using "localhost").  If possible, would you please link us to something internet-facing?